# insertion function for array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I am trying to make an insertion function and I want to pass an array of objects to it.

The program was working correctly but when I added the insertion function it stopped working correctly, because I don't know how to pass the parameter of the insertion function when I am calling it inside the main function.

Please help me to write the right call for the insertion function and if you have any important amendments or comments on the code write it please.

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

void insertfunction();
using namespace std;

struct workers {
    int no;
    char name[40];
    int age;
    int tel;
    char designationdate[14];
    char section[14];
    float monthlysalary;
} w;

const std::string  currentDateTime() {
    time_t     now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char       m,buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d.%X", &tstruct);

    return buf;
}

//next is the insertion function .
void insertfunction(workers w[20]) {
    int i;
    cout << "\n Enter the information of the worker who you want to add : ";
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        cout << "\n Enter worker no : ";
    cin >> w[i].no;
    cout << "\n Enter worker name : ";
    cin >> w[i].name;
    cout << "\n Enter worker age : ";
    cin >> w[i].age;
    cout << "\n Enter worker telephone : ";
    cin >> w[i].tel;
    cout << "\n Enter worker designation date : ";
    cin >> w[i].designationdate;
    cout << "\n Enter worker section : ";
    cin >> w[i].section;
    cout << "\n Enter worker monthly salary : ";
    cin >> w[i].monthlysalary;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* myfile;
    char pass1[10] = "ibraheem";
    char pass2[10];
    char pass3[10] = "22";
    char pass4[10];
    int k = 0;
    struct x;
    char m;// this variable belong to the time function .
    do {
        cout << "\n\n  enter your name : ";
        cin >> pass2;
    } while((strcmp(pass1,pass2)) != 0);
    do {
        cout << "\n\n  enter the password : ";
        cin >> pass4;
    } while((strcmp(pass3,pass4)) != 0);
    int a,i;
    cout << "\n\n               greenland bakeries group";
    cout << "\n\n                     sedra department \n\n";
    std::cout << "current Date Time is = " << currentDateTime() << std::endl;
    cout<<"\n\n\n  ";
    cout<<"\n\n\n Add a worker record : ";
    //next is the calling of the insertion function :
    insertfunction();
}
```

Comment: This is not how you should present your questions on SO. Say what your function is supposed to do. Explain in what way it is not working and give error codes if applicable. Indent your code so it is readable and try to only give the relevant bit of code - not the whole program... You will get a better response and more help like this.

Comment: Can't see how this is ever going to help anyone else. Also I don't understand why you use C-strings and C library functions, and why you declare `x`, `m`, `a`, `i` (terrible names) and a C file handle `myfile` ... none of which you ever use. Finally, you're not calling the function with any arguments, so no wonder it doesn't work. I suggest reading your C++ book again to learn the language before proceeding, because programming by guessing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass an array of workers to your function then the first think you must do is somewhere in your code declare an array of workers. In `main` seems the obvious place. Once you've declared the array it's easy to pass it to the function.

```
int main()
{
 ...
 workers w[20];
 insertfunction(w);
}
```

also delete `w` from this code

```
struct workers
{
int no;
char name[40];
int age;
int tel;
char designationdate[14];
char section[14];
float monthlysalary;
}w;
 ^ delete this
```

It declares a global variable called w. I can't see why you want that.

Some other tips

```
FILE *myfile;
```

and

```
int k=0;
struct x;
char m;// this variable belong to the time function .
```

and

```
int a,i;
```

None of these variables are being used in your code, delete these lines.

And what George Simms said is correct too.

Comment: Sam Redway thank you for the good advice , Lightness Races in Orbit thank you so much and i will learn more about c++ , George Simms you are totally right i did what you said and it has become excellent and john thank you so much .. now it goes right ..thanks for all of you guys .

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, your for loop is missing braces or indentation, so it will try to end the loop after the next semicolon.

This means at

```
cin>>w[i].no;
```

`i` will be out of scope.

Also `insertfunction` is declared to have an argument but is being called without any.